# What do -u, -m parameters do?

Tags: python, parameters

What do parameters `-u`, `-m` mean and what do they do?

for example:

```
python -u my_script.py
```

or

```
python -m my_script.py
```

Where can I read about them?

Comment: If you're on OSX or Linux try `man python` in your terminal window.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`-u` is used to force `stdin`,  `stdout`  and  `stderr` to be totally unbuffered, which otherwise is line buffered on the terminal

`-m` searches  `sys.path` for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script. An example would be `timeit` module. The command `python -m timeit "python script"` would return the time taken for the script to execute.

Quoting from the docs

> [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)
>
> Force `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to be totally unbuffered. On systems where it matters, also put `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in binary
>   mode.
>
> [`-m <module-name>`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m)
>
> Search `sys.path` for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module.

You can read more about them and other options [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)