# Strange print behavior with time.sleep in python

Tags: python, sleep

I was trying to create a progress-like thing by printing a dot every second on the same line. Something like "Fishing.....". This is what I used:

```
import time

print('Fishing', end='')
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('.', end='')
```

But it waits for 5 seconds and prints `Fishing.....` all at once. But when I don't use the `end=''`, it prints dots every second, but on separate lines like so

```
Fishing.
.
.
.
.
```

#### My questions:

1. Why does `print` behave this way?
2. How can I print a dot every second, but on the same line?

Comment: You can also use the `-u` argument. See [What do -u, -m parameters do?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32285796)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Why does `print` behave this way?

This has less to do with `print` and more with your terminal. For performance reasons, the text only gets "flushed" everytime there's a newline character, and not one character at a time.

2. How can I print a dot every second, but on the same line?

By "flushing" the standard output manually everytime you printed something:

```
import time
import sys

print('Fishing', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print('.', end='', flush=True)  # another way
```

If you need this all the time, you could define a seperate flushing print function:

```
from functools import partial
myprint = partial(print, end='', flush=True)
myprint('Fishing')
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    myprint('.')
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the `functools` thing. Would come in handy!

Answer (score 3):

This is because `print` is considered to be an *expensive* operation: it will usually wait until it has to print a lot of data, or until a new line is encountered (usually only if output is written to a terminal):

> **Output buffering is determined by file**. Use `file.flush()` to ensure, for instance, immediate appearance on a screen.

Evidently it is not expensive in the sense that it takes minutes: but asking the terminal operator to print new content, or the operating system to write data to a file (in case of I/O redirection) is still not "lightning fast".

You can force to print all data that is still in the queue, by using a [`flush` on the standard output channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230774/67579).

Comment: @Shadowfax: the new line is usually a policy used for terminals: since after a new line is printed, you sometimes ask a user a question.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
 print('.', end="", flush=True)
```